# Arrays using file_put_contents

Tags: php, arrays

Lets say I have 2 arrays .

```
$arr1=array("foo"=>"bar", 1=>"one", 2=>"two");
$arr2=array("h"=>"eich", 3=>"three", 4=>"four");
```

By using file_put_contents I am able to print the array into a new php file something like this :

```
<?php
$arr1 = Array
(
   "foo"=>"bar",
    1=>"one",
    2=>"two"
) //need a semicolon here 
$arr2 = Array
(
   "h"=>"eich",
    3=>"three",
    4=>"four"
)//need a semicolon here
```

My question is , How can I get a semicolon after the end of each array ?

Comment: it would help if you would show us the code you use for making this new php file.

Comment: @Nikola I just gave a small example  . Because the project that I am working on needs a comma after the end of each array

Comment: @jat: I have edited your post to be consise, because you said you wanted a comma after the end of each array, but I see you have accepted the DaveRandom's answer which means you needed the semicolon and not the comma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you even have this problem, I guess you are looping the arrays to convert them to PHP code and not using [`var_export()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) - which you should be:

```
$arr1 = array("foo"=>"bar", 1=>"one", 2=>"two");
$arr2 = array("h"=>"eich", 3=>"three", 4=>"four");

$file = "<?php\n\n".var_export($arr1, TRUE).";\n\n".var_export($arr2, TRUE).";\n";

file_put_contents('newfile.php', $file);
```

[See it working](http://codepad.org/5GcuI7Qr)